# Unsubscribe from Google Play Console "Families program"

Tags: google-play-console

My app has been approved for the "Designed for Families program" on the Google Play Console. But now I want to unsubscribe from the "Families program".

How can I do it?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to opt out the Designed for Families program of Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69084818/2821954)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unsubscribe from the Family Program: make your app 13+ in Google Play Console, then it will show that you have unsubscribed from the Family Program. But don't worry, the age rating will not be according to that.