# How to opt out the Designed for Families program of Google Play?

Tags: google-play

I have a free app available on Google Play. I got an email from Google Play after I submitted the 'Target audience and content' for this app on 'App content' page of Play Console today. It said that my app does not meet their eligibility criteria for the Designed for Families program.

As my app is designed for everyone, I decide not to participate in the Designed for Families program for the app.

Comment: Possibly related: [Unsubscribe from Google Play Console "Families program"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60473667/2821954)

Comment: Absolutely related, but "mine" answer shows step-by-step how to find that section.

Answer (score 11):

I've contacted the Google Play support, follows their reply:

> If your app is designed only for children, you must remain in the
> Designed for Families program. If your app is designed for older users
> and children, you can choose to not enroll in Designed for Families
> program. Note, if you wish to change the Designed for Families program
> enrollment status, you must complete the Target audience and content.
>
> Please follow this steps to opt out the Designed for families program:
>
> - Go to the Policy Section and select App Content.
> - Find **Target audience and content** and click "Managed"
> - Unchecked the three target aged group (5 and under, 6-8, 9-12) (See the attached screenshot)
> - Then finish updating the form and click submit.
>   [image: Google play console screenshot: age selection]

But even keeping all the age ranges at the step **4** of the process you can unroll from *Designed for Families program*:

[image: Google play console screenshot: Join the Designed for Families program selection]